# When does character and int concatenation result in seg fault?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int number = 900;
    cout << std::string("Hello, World!" + number) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I know the correct solution will be to use `std::to_string(number)`. But the question here is, why do I not get a segmentation fault? I even ran it through valgrind. The string length is around 13 and I move the pointer 900.

Comment: *Undefined behavior* is undefined

Comment: Can you refer some doc please, I would love to read further.

Comment: "_The string length is around 13 and I move the pointer 900_" - so you know what you're doing wrong. Why do you expect there to be anything useful in the random location in memory you are now pointing to?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub - not really sure what other kind of doc you are expecting. *Undefined behavior* means that you literally have no guarantee what is going to happen when you run the program

Comment: I like playing with fire :) Seems I just got lucky or un-lucky I didn't see seg fault :(

Comment: Note that the C++ standard *never* guarantees a segmentation fault - the words don't even appear in it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *expression* `"Hello, World!" + number` is a `const char[]` literal added to an `int`. The former decays to a `const char*` pointer and you add `number` to it by *pointer arithmetic*.

Since that final pointer is not in the original string constant, you are passing an invalid `const char*` pointer to a `std::string` constructor, and the behaviour of your program is undefined. *Anything* can happen at that point, including a runtime crash. An aggressively optimising compiler might omit the undefined expression altogether; that's getting progressively more common.

## Boom!

If you wanted to *concatenate* `900` to the string, then you could have written

```
std::cout << std::string("Hello, World!" + std::to_string(number)) << std::endl;
```

Comment: Well... not boom for the OP. That seems to be the source of their confusion.

Comment: @StoryTeller: I tried it on my box and my cat is now missing.

Comment: And the OP's cat is still in the box.

Comment: You of all people should know better by now :P But seriously. I think a few more words about the lack of guarantees inherent in UB will make this the proper answer.